# Bounding box of blob in image

Tags: c#, opencv, bounding-box

I have a grayscale image with black background, and some non-black objects on it like this:

[image]

Now I want to find the minimal (rectangle) bounding box for each object. I can provide a starting point inside each object if this helps.

Since there are no fancy thresholds or anything, I would like to avoid something like Canny to find the contures. If a pixel is not 0, it's in the blob.

Comment: Look for edge tracing algorithms.  If you don't know how many blobs, start by reading horizontal and vertical lines through the image, looking for blobbish things.  Once you find one, find an edge and trace it.  Then continue looking for the blobbish things, eliminating the one(s) you have already found.  The more rules about the blobs you know (minimum size, the number of blobs, etc), the faster this will run.  I just re-read, you have a starting point in the blog.  Look down from there to find an edge, then go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to plot rectangles around anything that is not completely black in your image you can do the following:

```
imagefile = '/path/to/your/image'
img = cv2.imread(imagefile)

# Convert you image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Threshold the image to extract only objects that are not black
# You need to use a one channel image, that's why the slice to get the first layer
tv, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray[:,:,0], 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Get the contours from your thresholded image
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

# Create a copy of the original image to display the output rectangles
output = img.copy()

# Loop through your contours calculating the bounding rectangles and plotting them
for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(output, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
# Display the output image
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

[image: output image with rectangles around non-zero objects]

Answer (score 0):

Well no matter what you use, you will still need to loop through all pixels. although `Bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)` is mostly used but it is very slow. but if you lock bits in the memory and loop over the byte array it will be hundreds of time faster.

please have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for locking bits of an image in memory.

Comment: Implementing some loop myself would not be the problem, I am also familiar with bit-locking. I was just thinking that such a simple objective can probably be done with some existing library functions, instead of re-inventing the wheel myself.

That also the library will likely loop through all pixels, yes, clear. But still, why re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a library exist or not. But if you had started inventing the wheel you had it by now.

Comment: Or I would still be debugging some weird edge case. @Carlos Melus version works great, so there is a library function for this.

And it's not like I spent the time waiting for the answer doodling around, but I did something else in the meantime. So overall this was still the fastest - and cleanest - solution.