# Creating bounding boxes on grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I have an image with persons(grayscale and segmented) and I would like to draw bounding boxes for each of the persons in an image. My input image is

[image]

And I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395239/bounding-box-of-blob-in-image) solution and this will give me a bounding boxes as shown below
[image]

When persons are close to each other it seems to give one bounding box here. Is there any approach where I can distinguish even if they are close to each other.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions exists for this, like "human shape recognition" using some algorithm, or using some AI

there are no "easy methods" for this, but you can look at this:

https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-project-real-time-human-detection-counting/

https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/detect-shapes-hough-transform-opencv-python

or some AI
https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-10-lines-of-code-d6cb4d86f606